# Angular routing was ignored

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have module `Board` with routes:

```
@Board.config ($routeProvider, $httpProvider,$locationProvider)->
  # Code
  $routeProvider
  .when '/boards/:board_id/topics/new', {
    templateUrl: (p) -> "/boards/#{p.board_id}/topics/new"
    controller: 'TopicsNewCtrl'
  }
  .when '/boards/:board_id', {
    templateUrl: (p) -> "/boards/#{p.board_id}"
    controller: 'BoardsShowCtrl'
  }
  .when '/boards', {
    templateUrl: "/boards"
    controller: 'BoardsShowCtrl'
  }
```

When I go to `/boards/common`, controller `BoardShowCtrl` executed correctly, but when I go to `/boards/common/topics/new` request goes directly to my Rails backend instead of angular routing. Here is my controller:

```
@Board.controller 'TopicsNewCtrl', [
  "$scope"
  "$routeParams"
  "$http"
  "topicsFctr"
  ($scope, $routeParams, $http, topicsFctr) ->
    $scope.board_id = $routeParams.board_id
]
```

I can't find an error in my code, it works with other controllers and templates. If you need some additional data - just ask.

Thank you for your answers!

P.S. Sorry for my English. It is so bad, I know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! There was another module with routing, matches my urls. It was so simple... and so stupid.